# AWS LifeCycle Manager stuck in loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, lifecycle

Has anybody experienced this or know how to fix it?

[image]

I've tried restarting the browser and trying incognito but it just won't load.

Comment: Try a different browser or a different network (home vs office vs tethered via your phone)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein still the same.. even if using different network/connection. (example I was at home when I did the screenshot, today i'm in the office but still the same stuck in loading"